# jQuery script working on jsfiddle, but not on my site?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that isn't working on my site. Neither Firebug nor Chrome's inspector report any bugs. I ran a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTXd6/7/) and it works just fine there. Any ideas on what the issue could be? I'm pretty stumped.

Here's my function:

```
$("#totop").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height: "50px"}, "slow");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height: "20px"}, "slow");    
    }
);
```

​

Comment: Extra character at the end of the code inserted by JSFiddle?

Comment: Oh sure, "something else on your page!"

Comment: Is that code wrapped in a DOM ready? jsFiddle does that part automatically.

Comment: try wrapping that code in a `$(function() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: Might you forgot to include jQuery library within `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and will work like a charm:=)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0px;padding:0px}
#totop{width:400px;
height:20px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 35%;width: 30%;
background: #78D3D9;
height: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#totop").hover(
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "50px"}, "slow");
},
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "20px"}, "slow");    
}
);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#topofpage"><div id="totop"></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for anybody else who comes along with the same question:

Wrap code in:

```
$(function() { /* your code here */ });
```